# Java substring error: String index out of range

Tags: java

I am working on this homework for school.  I am trying to figure out how to get individual words from a string given by the user.  In my case words are separated by spaces all the time.  So my code counts how many spaces there are and then makes substrings.  Please help if you can.

```
        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String userSentence=IO.readString();

        String testWord="";
        int countSpaces=0;


        for(int j=0; j<userSentence.length(); j++){
            if((userSentence.charAt(j))==' '){
                countSpaces++;

            }
        }


        for(int i=0; i<userSentence.length(); i++){
            if(countSpaces>0){

                while(userSentence.charAt(i)==' '){
                    i++;
                    countSpaces--;
                }

                testWord=userSentence.substring(i, userSentence.indexOf(" "));
                i=i+(testWord.length()-1);

            }

            if(countSpaces==0){
                testWord=userSentence.substring(i);
                i=userSentence.length();
            }

            System.out.print(testWord);
```

Comment: You need to count how many spaces has the sentence and then remove them?

Comment: i need to count how many words there are in a given phrase or sentence.  And spaces are what distinguish between words.  The problem that is occuring is with 
                testWord=userSentence.substring(i, userSentence.indexOf(" "));

Comment: Well, instead for doing those looping you can use `split(" ")`. If you use this method on a `String` it'll break your `String` into an array of `Strings`. The `String` you pass as parameter to the `split()` method will be the "break point" of the `String`. 

Example: `"testing split like a boss".split(" ") -> ["testing", "split", "like", "a", "boss"]`

Comment: i am not allowed to use arrays just yet.  it has to be done in a loop of some sort

Comment: im just not really sure what is wrong with my code now.  I went through it on a piece of paper.  the number for the index should be correct.

Comment: What is the line that throws the error?

Comment: testWord=userSentence.substring(i, userSentence.indexOf(" "));

Comment: @TIMOTHYKINSEY
Try debugging it with a debugger. If you haven't learnt to use a debugger yet, try adding extra print statements to investigate by yourself what is wrong. E.g. before the line with the error, add:

`System.out.println("i=" + i + " indexOfSpace=" + userSentence.indexOf(" ") + " userSentenceLength=userSentence.length());`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t supply the entire code portion, I will just point out a problem with what you have posted…

Below is a your `for` loop with “ i ” as its counter…

```
for(int i=0; i<userSentence.length(); i++)
{
              // … Rarely (if ever) is “ i ” changed inside this loop!
  i++;                     // <--- this will cause a problem
  i=userSentence.length(); // <--- so will this
}
```

This sets up to loop thru every character in the `userSentence`. " i " is the counter variable for the loop. If you change the counter variable “ i ” inside the loop (which you do several times), then you will most likely get unexpected results. “ i ” is automatically incremented by the loop construct. If you change it, the loop will most likely break or not work as expected.

Your error when you get to...

```
testWord=userSentence.substring(i, userSentence.indexOf(" "));
```

Is not unusual considering it uses " i " as an index.
 Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The below code would be a lot cleaner if we didn't have to count the spaces, but I'm assuming that's your constraint, so I'm rolling with it. (Edit: kudos to JohnG in that there's better ways to go about this than changing `i`)

The problem is that the `userSentence.indexOf(" ")` function will always return the *first* found location of `" "`, and since you keep incrementing `i` but don't make any changes to `userSentence`, the `substring(i, userSentence.indexOf(" "))` command ceases to make sense.

The solution to the above would be to declare a `remainder` String that keeps track of the part of `userSentence` remaining after the next `testWord` is found.

Another caveat is that `indexOf()` will return -1 if no occurence of `" "` is found, which in this case means that you're on your last word. In that case, the of `testWord` would be set to the end of `remainder`.

Here's what I've got. Again, super-clunky, but I'm trying to not rewrite everything you've got:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
    String userSentence=IO.readString();

    String testWord="";
    int countSpaces=0;

    for(int j=0; j<userSentence.length(); j++){
        if((userSentence.charAt(j))==' '){
            countSpaces++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<userSentence.length(); i++){
       while(i<userSentence.length() && userSentence.charAt(i)==' '){
          i++;
          countSpaces--;
       }       
       if(i<userSentence.length()){
          String remainder = userSentence.substring(i);

          if(countSpaces==0){
             testWord=userSentence.substring(i);
             i=userSentence.length();
          } else    {
             remainder = userSentence.substring(i);
             int endOfWordIndex = remainder.indexOf(" ");       //  set end of word to first occurrence of " "   
             if(endOfWordIndex == -1){                          //  if no " " found,
             endOfWordIndex = remainder.length();           //      set end of word to end of sentence.
          }

          testWord=remainder.substring(0, endOfWordIndex);              
          i=i+(testWord.length()-1);
        }

  System.out.println("word: '" + testWord + "'");
```